# What's the difference between "JOIN FETCH" and "JOIN"?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

Supposing I have a `Person` entity that has `@OneToMany` relationship with `Phone` entity. If I want to eagerly fetch `Phone` entities associated with a `Person`, I got 2 options:

```
SELECT p FROM Person p JOIN p.phones
```

or

```
SELECT p FROM person p JOIN FETCH p.phones
```

So what is the difference between them?

Comment: https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_fetch_joins

Comment: The difference is that only `JOIN FETCH` will fetch the phones eagerly.

Comment: JOIN FETCH will *request* that the JPA implementation will fetch the phones eagerly (but doesn't have to do it).

Comment: Thanks, I just misunderstanded the `JOIN` key word. @KlasLindbäck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that, in the end, JOIN FETCH is always a JOIN.
By default `@OneToMany` relationships are lazy loaded.
Using JOIN FETCH you load the related entities in advance.

You can find more info reading [FETCH JOIN is still a JOIN](http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/10/fetch-join-is-still-a-join/) by Piotr Nowicki